# align label in right and left for input

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i want to create input form with it label using dl dt dd list, the first label in left and second in right and input in center, i already spend hour to fix this issue. The problem is that i can put the first label in right or left, but the second does not go to left or right and be side by side by input...

here is example:

[image: desired layout]

Here is what I tried so far:

```css
dt {
  clear: both;
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}

label {
  font: 11px Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

dd {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

PS: I really want to keep using dl dt dd..

Comment: What about the `input description`? Should this not be rendered at all? Can it be removed from HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what u r expecting add `display:flex`  and  `justify-content:space-between` property to `.inline` class.

```
.inline{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
margin:0px 10px;
}
```

```css
.inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

using `float`:

```css
.inline {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

label {
  font: 11px Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

dd {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt class="left"><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt class="right"><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

using `positioning` properties.

```css
.inline {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt class="left"><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd class="center">
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt class="right"><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: Yes, it looks good, but can you do it without flex as I tried...above and follow my existing css just to fix it if i am missing something?

Comment: @Robert checkout my answer I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Simply float everything to the left:

```css
dt,
dd {
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
}
dd small {
  display:block;
}

/* to center everything*/
dl {
 display:table;
 margin:auto;
}
/**/

label {
  font: 11px Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

dl, dd, dt are just html elements which by default are block elements. So already by styling all these elements to be inline or inline-block, they will be on the same line.

```css
.inline > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

one of the solutions is to use flex.

Note: This solution could vary depending on the browsers you need to support and if the form should be responsive or not, and I would say if you have any kind of CSS architecture.

```css
dl.inline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.inline dt {
  width: 25%;
}
.inline dt:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

.inline dd {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  font: 11px Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

No **flex**. **inline** solution.

```css
dl {
  text-align: center;
}

dt {
  display: inline-block;
}

label {
  font: 11px Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

dd {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

small {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<dl class="inline">
  <dt><label for="name">label1</label></dt>
  <dd>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="text" />
    <small>input description</small>
  </dd>
  <dt><label for="name">label2</label></dt>
</dl>
```

Comment: yes, i really need it without flex for example using position relative, display.. float...if that possible please?

Comment: @Robert, I made a solution using `inline-block`. Check, pls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this.

```css
div {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<div>
        <label>label1</label>
        <input type="text">
        <label>label2</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i know how to do it with div, but as i said i want to keep dl dt dd list, is that possible?